# Problem with references (,n,d,a)

Tags: bibliographies, citing

I am sorry if this is a basic question, but after a week of fiddling I hope somebody here can help me solve this issue. I am not an advanced user, but I have used LaTeX for 5 years and never had this problem before.

Out of my 68 references, 2 seem faulty. They output (,n.d.a) and (,.n.d.b). According to google "n.d" might stand for "no date", however my references contain year. To what I can see, they look **exactly** like the other articles/miscellaneous referenced.

```
@article{gordon1954
  title={The economic theory of a common-property resource: the fishery},
  author={Gordon, H S},
  journal={Journal of Political Economy},
  volume = {62},
  number = {1},
  pages={124--142},
  year={1954},
  publisher={Springer}
}

@misc{icesmack
  author={ISEC},
  title={Latest advice 2019: ICES advice on fishing opportunities, catch, and effort - Mackerel},
  year={2019},
  url = {http://ices.dk/sites/pub/Publication\%20Reports/Advice/2019/2019/mac.27.nea.pdf},
  note = {Accessed: 2010-02-25. This is one example of a report. Other species' reports can be found at the ICES advice page}
}
```

I have tried commenting out different elements but it doesn't help...

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: you are missing the commas after the keys (`gordon1954` and `icesmack`).

Comment: Unrelated to your issue, but given name initials should be given with a `.` in the input. Instead of \*`author={Gordon, H S},` write `author={Gordon, H. S.},`.  Usually special characters like `%` need not be escaped in the `url` field (because it is treated differently from normal text fields), so `url = {http://ices.dk/sites/pub/Publication%20Reports/Advice/2019/2019/mac.27.nea.pdf},` with `%20` would be better than `\%20`.

Comment: Thank you, this is life-saving!